# How to use ORALCE SQL SEQUENCE in spring batch writer.?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

can someone please let me know how to use oracle sequence in spring batch writer?.

I tried using custseq.nextval in the insert statement, but its failing.

```
<bean id="testSSRReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="bconnectedDataSource" />
    <property name="sql"
        value="select CUST_USA_ID , CUST_FIRST_NAME , CUST_LAST_NAME from BL_CUSTOMER fetch first 100 rows only" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.macys.batch.rowmapper.TestSSRRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="testSSRProcessor" class="com.macys.batch.processor.TestSSRProcessor" />
<bean id="testSSRWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ocDataSource" />
    <property name="sql">
        <value>
            <![CDATA[        
                insert into TESTTABLESSR(CUSTOMER_ID,CUSTOMER_NAME,CITY)
                     VALUES (custseq.nextval,:firstName,:lastName)
                ]]>
        </value> 
    </property>
    <property name="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider" ref="itemSqlParameterSourceProvider" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What way is it failing exactly?